# Some features of a Bootstrap calendar do not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, calendar

I'm trying to implement this Bootstrap 3 calendar: http://bootstrap-calendar.azurewebsites.net/index-bs3.html (you can of course see its innards by looking at the source)

However, there are problems. Firstly, the checkbox to toggle modals do not work. Rather, to enable modals, one has to first click a day in the calendar (to get the black dropdown menu), and then they are enabled.

Secondly, the navigational buttons (week, day, month, prev, next, today) do not work at all. No error is caught. Only this warning:

`Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.`

Here's the relevant JS and HTML code:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}underscore/underscore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}bootstrap-calendar/js/calendar.js"></script>
</head>
```

And

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="page-header">

        <div class="pull-right form-inline">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" data-calendar-nav="prev"><< Prev</button>
                <button class="btn" data-calendar-nav="today">Today</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" data-calendar-nav="next">Next >></button>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button class="btn btn-warning" data-calendar-view="year">Year</button>
                <button class="btn btn-warning active" data-calendar-view="month">Month</button>
                <button class="btn btn-warning" data-calendar-view="week">Week</button>
                <button class="btn btn-warning" data-calendar-view="day">Day</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span9">
            <div id="calendar"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="span3">

                <label class="checkbox">
                    <input checked type="checkbox" value="#events-modal" id="events-in-modal"> Open events in modal window
                </label>
            <h4>Events</h4>
            <ul id="eventlist" class="nav nav-list"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script LANGUAGE="javascript">
        var calendar = $("#calendar").calendar(
            {
                tmpl_path: "{{ STATIC_URL }}bootstrap-calendar/tmpls/",
                modal: "#events-modal",
            events_source: [

        {
            "id": 293,
            "title": "{{ user }}",
            "url": "http://example.com",
            "class": "event-important",
            "start": 1406160000000, // Milliseconds
            "end": 1406205837000 // Milliseconds
        }]
            });         
    </script>



    <div class="modal fade" id="events-modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h3>Event</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" style="height: 400px">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Close</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you see the app.js in the calendar bootstrap, you can view how they initialize the buttons... it's not on the "core", you need to do too

EDIT:
You have all of them in app.js:

```
$('.btn-group button[data-calendar-nav]').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.click(function() {
        calendar.navigate($this.data('calendar-nav'));
    });
});

$('.btn-group button[data-calendar-view]').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.click(function() {
        calendar.view($this.data('calendar-view'));
    });
});

$('#first_day').change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    value = value.length ? parseInt(value) : null;
    calendar.setOptions({first_day: value});
    calendar.view();
});

$('#language').change(function(){
    calendar.setLanguage($(this).val());
    calendar.view();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry can you explain a bit more? How do I initialize them?

Comment: Hehe thanks, I just hadn't realized exactly where or if I was to put these. I thought calendar.js maybe imported app.js itself, but now I know it's my responsibility to put that code there. Thanks

Comment: You need to put on your page where has the buttons... in a $(document).ready()...